# ??? Error using ==> urlread at 111

Tags: matlab

I am trying to download from http and save in local folder.at first it works but now show this  problem
"Error downloading URL. Your network connection may be down or your proxy settings improperly configured."
I do not know about Java.
Anybody can explain me clearly.

Here's my code:

```
URL = 'http://e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov/MOLT/MOD11A1.005/2013.02.29/';
% Local path on your machine
localPath = 'E:\DATA\MOD11A1';

% Read html contents and parse file names with ending *.hdf
urlContents = urlread(URL);
 ret = regexp(urlContents, '"\S+\.hdf\.xml"', 'match');
 ret = regexp(urlContents, '"\S+\.hdf"', 'match');

% Loop over all files and download them
for k=1:length(ret)
    filename = ret{k}(2:end-1);
    if isequal(filename(19),'2')==1 && (isequal(filename(20),'1')==1 || isequal(filename(20),'2')==1 || isequal(filename(20),'3')==1) && isequal(filename(22),'0')==1 && (isequal(filename(23),'5')==1 || isequal(filename(23),'6')==1)
    filepathOnline = strcat(URL, filename);
    filepathLocal = fullfile(localPath, filename);
    urlwrite(filepathOnline, filepathLocal);
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

The February 2013 has 28 days, there is no 2013.2.29.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that there is an error in the URL you define in the first line. Please doublecheck the correctness, if it is indeed correct, you should probably contact the administrator of the server that the site is on.